# Comparing file with a list of files using filecmp.cmp(file1, file2)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function with three args

- list_to_copy : list of files that I want to copy.
- list_to_avoid : list that I don't want to copy, that might exists in list_to_copy
- the destination is the path where the file is going to be.

```
    def copy_files(self, list_to_copy, list_to_avoid, destination):
        # Copy a file from list to destination making sure file is not 
        # duplicated regarding the name.
        for copied_file in list_to_copy:
            for avoid_file in list_to_avoid:
                if not filecmp.cmp(copied_file, avoid_file):
                    shutil.copy(copied_file, destination)
```

My main problem is I don't know how to compare `copied_file` with all files in `list_to_avoid` using `filecmp.cmp(file1, file2)`

---

***Note checking by name of the file (string) isn't efficient for me.***

Comment: is the problem that what you have is just inefficient?

Comment: @ChaseLp I am not that advanced. I am renaming files after I copy them, so I need to compare with a different way to avoid duplicating files. if you have suggestion help me out ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from filecmp import cmp
from shutil import copy
from os import scandir
def copy_files(list_to_copy,destination):
# Copy a file from list to destination making sure file is not duplicated regarding the content.
    for copied_file in list_to_copy:
        for avoid_file in scandir(destination):
            if cmp(copied_file,avoid_file):
                break
        else:
            copy(copied_file, destination)
```

Comment: That won't work for me, since the strings will be changed after the process due to rename. My code continuously copying files from path A to B then rename them at path B with date and time. So for the next cycle, the name is changed so the same file with a different name will be added each cycle. But thanks for the help ^_^

Comment: I do not understand. Is the list list_to_avoid changed after making each copy? Or is it changed every time the function is called?

Comment: If it is changed after making every copy then add last line: list_to_avoid.append("[NEW THING TO AVOID]")

Comment: `list_to_copy` is changed every time the function is called. These two files are the same but the one with the date is renamed but the GUID named is copied again in the next cycle of the code [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/260869377333788672/848405971054624818/unknown.png)

Comment: list_to_avoid.append("[NEW THING TO AVOID]") This can work but only for one session, maybe a data file that contains a history of copied files. Still, I want to avoid data files.

Comment: Please clarify which files that are in list list_to_copy you do not want to be copied. Do I understand correctly that you want to skip all files in list list_to_copy that have same content as any of the files in destination folder?

Comment: Yes, exactly that is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I try to write you the code. It might take about 20 minutes.

Comment: Thank you, I will work on it later and see how it goes. You can add me on discord > VERX#2227 to avoid conversations here.

Comment: Edited it now. Try it.